# Fdisk lists total hard drive space as 500G but lists a partition as 922G

Tags: fdisk

Here is my `fdisk` output in the picture below. There seems to be some major discrepancies here. You can see that `/dev/sda` is only a 500 gig drive but contains nearly a 1 TB size partition on `sda3`. What is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by a legacy MBR when the disk is actually using a GUID partition table (GPT): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

Also, it looks like you use a RAID on this machine, spanning two physical disks.